# If $c$ is a complex root of a cubic $a(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ is the root field of $a(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 31, Exercise C4.

> Prove that if $c$ is a complex root of a cubic $a(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$,
> then $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ is the root field of $a(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Given $c$ is a complex root of $a(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x]$,
so is the conjugate $\bar{c}$.  So $a(x)=(x-c)(x-\bar{c})b(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ for some polynomial $b(x)$ . Note $b(x)$ has degree 1, and so the root of $b(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(c)$.

Is this a reasonable argument?

Update:
Turns out this is a duplicate of [Splitting Field of Cubic Polynomial Over the Rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850518/splitting-field-of-cubic-polynomial-over-the-rationals).

Comment: This does not seem right. How about $a(x)=x^3-2$ and $c=\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$?

Comment: Does root field mean splitting field? If so, then this isn't true by @lhf's example. In fact,  an irreducible cubic over $Q$ with a complex root can't have splitting field of degree $3$ (rather it must be $6$), since adjoining the real root can't give you the complex roots. Maybe root field means something else.

Comment: Here is the definition from Pinter's Abstract Algebra in Chapter 31: If $a(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $F[x]$, let its roots be $c_1, \cdots, c_n$. Then $F(c_1, \cdots, c_n)$ is clearly the smallest extension of $F$ containing all the roots of $a(x)$. $F(c_1, \cdots, c_n)$ is called the root field of $a(x)$ over $F$.

Comment: So it means the same as the splitting field, in which case the theorem as written above is false -- more than that, for irreducible cubics over $Q$, it is never the case that adjoining a single non-real root will generate the splitting field of the cubic.